# convert instance variable into string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have a uiviewcontroller with a instance variable "direction". I can do
MyViewController.direction

but if I don't want the value but a string with the variable name, so I want @"direction".

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish? The same object could be referenced by thousands of instance variables, so you can't go from an object to an instance variable name. And if you know precisely which instance variable you want the name of, you could just type the variable's name yourself. So I'm not clear on what use you'd have for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the list of properties using `class_copyPropertyList` and you can use `property_getName` to retrieve the name of the property passing the struct returned by the first method.

You can read more on that in Objective-C Runtime programming guide in the Declared Properties section.